# dereferencing a pointer to struct inside function in c

Tags: c, pointers

I have a .h file like this:

```c
struct Node{
    struct Node *previous;
    struct Node *next;
    char *data;
};

struct Queue{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
};

int Queue_init(struct Queue *queue, struct Node *node){

    queue->head = node;
    queue->tail = node;
    return 0;
}

int Queue_push(struct Queue *queue, struct Node *node){

    node->next = NULL;
    if(queue->tail == NULL){
        queue->head = node;
        node->previous = NULL;
    } else {
        node->previous = queue->tail;
        queue->tail->next = node;
    }
    queue->tail = node;    
    return 0;
}

int Queue_pop(struct Queue *queue, struct Node *node){

    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",node->data);
    if(queue->head == NULL){
        node->data = NULL;    
    } else{
        node = queue->head;
        if(queue->head->next == NULL){
            queue->head = NULL;
            queue->tail = NULL;
        } else {
            queue->head = queue->head->next;
            queue->head->previous = NULL;
        }
    }    
    node->previous = NULL;
    node->next = NULL;
    fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",node->data);    
    return 0;
}
```

My .c file is like this:

```c
int main(){
    struct Node *node_0 = malloc(3*sizeof(void*));
    node_0->data = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(node_0->data, "Hello");
    struct Queue *queue_0 = malloc(2*sizeof(void*));
    Queue_init(queue_0, node_0);
    struct Node *node_1 = malloc(3*sizeof(void*));
    node_1->data = malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(node_1->data, "World");
    Queue_push(queue_0, node_1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", queue_0->head->data, queue_0->head->next->data);
    Queue_pop(queue_0, node_1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %s\n", node_1->data, queue_0->head->data);
    free(queue_0);
    free(node_0->data);
    free(node_0);
    free(node_1);
    free(node_1->data);
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting the results that I want with the queue_pop function.
The results I get are:

```
Hello World
World
Hello
World World
```

Basically, when I pop something out of the queue, I want to save it into the second parameter of the function, which is node_1, but it is not. I believe this might have something with dereferencing pointers in functions.

I get WHY my code is not working. But HOW do I get it to work? (That node_1->data should be equal to "Hello" after exiting the function).

Thanks. By the way, my first time posting, if anyone can tell me how to post the code without messing it up, that'll be helpful too.

Comment: Format/indent your question properly.

Comment: @Olaf:  It is usually pretty easy to fix for them.  I did it in about 15 seconds.  That would be better to do than biting them.

Comment: To indent text (which causes it to format as code), select the lines and press Ctrl-K.

Comment: I would use `malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`. Also, you should initialize all the pointers to NULL;

Comment: @wallyk: If you clean the kid's room instead of getting it to clean itselfselves, it will never learn.

Comment: Don't have variable or function definitions in your header file (except for `inline` functions).

Comment: even inline function in .h creates issues.